# How to hide server name in response in case of TRACE http Method in spring MVC

Tags: spring, trace, servlet-3.0

I am working on fixing Penetration testing items. As per reported issue, server name display in response when tester penetrate our web application request and change "TRACE"/OPTIONS/PUT/DELETE/HEAD from "GET" and we get below response.

```
    Request Header - 

    TRACE /MyWebApp/ApplicationDetails HTTP/1.1

    Host: 10.253.435.736:8080

    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 
    Firefox/50.0

    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0103C35D187B18V53A0E9B7C3D0F36E6

    Connection: close
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

    Response Header - 
    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Allow: POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 18:07:42 GMT
    Connection: close
```

To restrict PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE , HEAD method I have written below code in web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
         <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
         <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
         <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
         <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
```

I have created a Servlet exception handler class as follows to handle servlet exception

```
    @WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
    public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public AppExceptionHandler() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            processError(request, response);
            }

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            processError(request, response);
            }

        public void doTrace(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            processError(request, response);
        }
        public void service(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            processError(request, response);
        }
        private void processError(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            // Analyze the servlet exception
            if (response != null) {
                response.addHeader("Server", StringUtils.EMPTY);
            }
            Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
            Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
            String servletName = (String) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
            if (servletName == null) {
                servletName = "Unknown";
            }
            String requestUri = (String) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
            if (requestUri == null) {
                requestUri = "Unknown";
            }
            String pageName="error";
            // Set response content type
              response.setContentType("text/html");

              if(statusCode == 403 || statusCode == 405){
                  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED); 
              }
              else if(statusCode == 404){
                  pageName="404";
              }

              try {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/" + pageName + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I have mapped above class with below setting in web.xml

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
      </error-page>
      <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
      </error-page>
      <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
      </error-page>
        <error-page>
            <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
            <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
      </error-page>
      <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
      <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
      <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
    </error-page>
```

After implementing above code and web.xml config entry, our application does not display server name for OPTIONS/HEAD/PUT/DELETE http method while it display for TRACE http method. When we replace GET with TRACE it neither hit our servlet exception handler class "AppExceptionHandler" nor any Filter class and it display server name as shown above.

In short, above fix is working in all case except TRACE http method.

I don't understand what should I do to fix this issue.

As this is my first post in this forum so please guide me in case I missed any information.

Comment: You are making it way to complex... Just configure your  Tomcat accordingly instead of trying to fix this at the application level. Configure the `Connector` in your `server.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your guidance Deinum. I just started working in spring java from last one month. I am a hard core .net developer. It would be really great in case you can demonstrate some sample configuration of connector configuration element that resolve my issue. Actually my web.xml entry restrict TRACE http method but it display server name. I don't want to display server name in response header,

Comment: See [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) this feature has been available since tomcat 4 (or something like that). What you see is the default, you can set it to whatever you want. For a bit more detailed description see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#web.xml) and actually that whole document which also describes how to disable it for error pages.